# ZxingObjc Integration IOS not Working properly

Tags: ios, xcode6, zxing

I have integrated ZxingObjc framework in ios Application.But i cant able read qrcode using that library.The below method is not triggering after read QRcode
- (void)captureResult:(ZXCapture *)capture result:(ZXResult *)result

Thanks & Regards,
Sam.P